# TypeScript error: Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I keep getting this error:

```
> TypeScript error: Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Navigator'
```

while using this code:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

I have the following plugins:

```
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2"/>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3"/>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2"/>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2"/>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3"/>
> <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
```

What might be wrong with my code?

Comment: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add an app property to the Navigator interface

```
interface Navigator {
    app: {
        exitApp: () => any; // Or whatever is the type of the exitApp function
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to confirm app exit through the device back button and was told to use `navigator.app.exitApp();` to actually exit upon user confirmation.

Comment: So, I  don't know what the content of the exitApp function is.

Comment: I have provided a pretty generic type for `exitApp` it should work with your code

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I can't fully understand how or where do I have to use this code. Can please someone hive me a hint?

Answer (score 14):

**1. Inject to global**

```js
declare global {
  interface Navigator {
    app: any;
  }
}
navigator.clipboard; // origin property
navigator.app.exitApp(); // inject property
```

**2. As any**

```
(navigator as any).app.exitApp();
```

This should works.

**3. declare a new interface**

Check the typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts if you had import the dom lib.

```
interface NavigatorCordova extends Navigator {
    app: {
        exitApp: () => any; // Or whatever is the type of the exitApp function
    }
}
(navigator as NavigatorCordova).app.exitApp();
```

Just like this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083037/9515185

Answer (score 2):

you need to have relevant typings.

**1) install typings package**

```
npm install typings --global
```

**2) install the the relavant typing for the package, if you are not certain about the plugins typing name, you can search too.**

```
typings search cordova-plugin-device-orientation

typings install dt~cordova-plugin-device-orientation --global --save
```

and you are good to go